# what is difference between different forms of instantiation of a class in C++?

Tags: c++

If a class has a constructor with the arguments as defined below

```
class myclass
{
    public:
        myclass(int a, int b)
        {
            cout << a << b << endl;
        }
};
```

can anybody please let me know the differences between the 2 forms of object instantiation as mentioned below.

```
myclass ob(2, 3);
myclass ob = myclass(2, 3);
```

Comment: No. It is not duplicate.